# Reflect property change from one ViewModel to another

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I have this WPF/MVVM Application that a TabControl with a bunch of tabs. When the app loads, data for all tabs are loaded. There are some calculations that are made on Tab1 that's dependent on values from Tab2. what's happening is, when I enter / change data on tab2, it simply doesn't reflect on Tab1 when I click on Tab1. under the hood, the calculations are made properly but it doesn't reflect on tab1. I have to go to the main tab to re-load all the data to reflect changes. Any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: have u implemented INotifyPropertyChanged for the relevant data-bound properties?

Comment: It's hard to answer this confidently without seeing some code.  It's a good idea to create a new test project and make a very simple proof of concept for what you're trying to achieve (ie you might have a TextBlock on tab1 showing the value from a TextBox on tab2).  9 times out of 10 you will come to the solution yourself, but if you don't you can post the code and someone here can put you on the right track.

Comment: I do have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged. It reflects the changes on the tab I am on. Meaning, the when I enter the values in Tab2, I get the results reflected on the View. But I need it done on the first Tab. I know its hard to suggest anything w/o looking at the code. but I'm refrained from taking outside of the company.

Comment: I understand that, but you can create a small test application and post the code from that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your view model data properties. Then, have your view model subscribe to the event (the `Initialize()` method is called by the view model constructor):

```
private void Initialize()
{

    // Subscribe to events
    this.PropertyChanging += OnPropertyChanging;
    this.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    this.Books.CollectionChanging += OnBooksCollectionChanging;
}
```

The view model handler for the event can then update any properties that need to be updated:

```
void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "FirstProperty":
             this.SomeOtheProperty = whatever;
            break;

        case "Another property":
            this.YetAnotherProperty = somethingElse;
            break;
    }
}
```

That should get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

If two **different** ViewModels need to show the same data/value they should bind to the same ViewModel.

I think that adding a binding between ViewModels is bad because it introduces a lot of dependencies.

If a property of a single ViewModel is dependent on an other property of the **same** ViewModel you could use property changed notification as mentioned in David's answer.